# How to undo changes introduced by a merge

Tags: git, merge

When merging develop into master I got a changes in master that makes master != develop even though they should have been identical. Reason for that is probably someone pushing conflicted files earlier in the project which has been fixed by changes in master that were not in develop.

I don't want to reset to the hash since then I get the same problem with next merge.
I want my develop-branch to be merged with master and then reset the files (not HEAD) to the hash develop had before merging so that when i commit git diff  returns nothing. Is this possible with git commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand your question correctly, the files in master are correct, a merge from develop introduces unwanted changes. Correct?

In this case you probably just want to merge develop in using a strategy that keeps your files unchanged.

```
git merge develop -s ours
```

Comment: correct, excpet the other way around. so `git checkout develop; git merge master -s ours` worked wonders.